# Add some logic in array filing

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to fill an array and I want to add some logic in it so it won't give me back errors...

Here is the code:

```
$entries_mixes = array();

foreach ($entries_query->result_array() as $entry) {


   $entries_mixes[] = array('title' => $entry['title'],
        'body' => $entry['body'],
        'author' => $entry['author'],
        'date_time' => $entry['date_time'],
        'id' => $entry['id'],
        'mix_name' => $mix['name'],
        'photo_name' =>$photo['name']
    );


}
```

what I want to do is to be able to check if some of the variables exist before I put them into the array....
so for example `if(isset($mix['name'])) then insert to array or else do nothing`

The point is not having undeclared variables trying to be inserted to my array cause it gives back errors...thanks!

Comment: Hmm, there are a couple of different interpretations of this question... do you want to omit an entry completely from `$entries_mixes` if any of its values aren't set? Or do you want every result to appear in `$entries_mixes`, with each result possibly having missing values?

Comment: thanks everybody for fast replies...@Richard: setting values to null would do the job for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `? :` ternary operator:

```
  $entries_mixes[] = array( 
       'title' =>  (isset($entry['title'])  ? $entry['title']  : null),
       'author' => (isset($entry['author']) ? $entry['author'] : null),
  ...
```

alternatively, use `empty()` for the check

Comment: To extend this use `array_filter` without a callback as second parameter to remove all items equal to `false` (e.g. `null`).

Answer (score 0):

The following will check if `title` doesn't exists in the `entry` array or if it's blank. If so, it'll skip the entry completely and continue to the next element in the loop.

```
$entries_mixes = array();

foreach ($entries_query->result_array() as $entry) {
  if (empty($entry['title'])) {
    continue;
  }

  $entries_mixes[] = array('title' => $entry['title'],
    'body' => $entry['body'],
    'author' => $entry['author'],
    'date_time' => $entry['date_time'],
    'id' => $entry['id'],
    'mix_name' => $mix['name'],
    'photo_name' =>$photo['name']
  );

}
```

Comment: `empty($entry['title'])` is already equivalent to `!isset($entry['title']) || !$entry['title']`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) so that if the variables don't exist, `NULL` is used as the value. But you actually want to omit certain keys from the array altogether in that case. So just set each key separately:

```
$entry[] = array();
...
if (isset($mix['name'])) {
    $entry['mix_name'] = $mix['name'];
}
...
$entries_mixes[] = $entry;
```